# Uninstall Packet Tracer which is installed using wine

Tags: linux, kali-linux, delete, uninstall, cisco

I have installed Packet Tracer 7.2.2(.exe file) using wine and have uninstalled it using the same uninstall.exe file provided. When uninstalled all the files of packet tracer are removed except the icon in the image. Initially i wasn't worried about it but now when i want to install packet tracer i used PacketTracer 7.3.1 (.deb file) using normal linux installation procedure, it is installed but when i am running

```
packettracer
```

in the terminal the app associated with this icon is running(which only icon is present).
I have tried uninstalling the packet tracer(with `apt purge packettracer`) and ran`locate packettracer` command and removed all the files associated with the packet tracer, but still the icon is not removed.
I tried for searching for packet tracer in all the locations mentioned in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674222/how-to-uninstall-packettracer)

ps:After removing all the packet tracer 7.2.2(which was installed using wine) files i have installed the PacketTracer7.3.1.deb package but when i run `packettracer` in terminal, i am getting the image_2[image: image_2] output but the app was not running. And when i see the menu after installation it is image_3[image: image_3].

[image: image_1]image_1: image before insatalling packetTracer7.3.1.

1.Is there any way to remove packet tracer completely(so that i can re-install the packet tracer debian package).

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove  packettracer
sudo apt-get remove packettracer
sudo apt-get clean
```

If they won’t work please send the output of these commands